# Как создать паттерн для N-ное количество объектов?

Tags: c#, .net

Как создать паттерн для N-ное количество объектов (данный пример для одного(singleton pattern))?

```
using System;

public class A 
{
    static A instance = null;

    public static A ff()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new A();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("constructor"); }
    }
}

public class M
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = A.ff();
        A b = A.ff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Нестерук хорошо рассказывает и показывает [здесь](https://youtu.be/Dk_ZqdLgLzY). Единственно, по поводу его предпочтений в работе с публичными полями вместо свойств, я бы на вашем месте, пока пропустил мимо ушей и все тоже самое писал бы используя свойства.

Comment: спасибо конечно за видео и совет,но то что я не понимаю,заключается вот в чем(конкретно на примере вопроса):думаю это реализовать так- использовать 1 статическое переменное чтобы знать сколько объектов создалось(например static int n) и когда это переменное меньше допустим 10(N)(if n<10) то можно создать новый объект, else больше не создать объекты(значит можно создать только 10 объектов этого класса, а если попробовать создать 11-ый,то просто не создается объект).Как создать N количество instance-ов и вернуть что(return)?P.S. приватный Конструктор,а объект создается через public static A ff()

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Ну и расскажите немного про логику использования этих N объектов.

Comment: дело вот в чём: в уроках C#  тема была паттерны (singleton pattern) и в конце лекции ест задание <<паттерн для Н-ное количество объектов>> и вот мне нужно конкретная реализация именно в виде кода(чтоб я был уверен что это точно правильно(реализация)) и уже изучить что к чему и зачем, чтобы хорошо усвоить тему(да можете предлагать и другой метод освоения(но пожалуйста не судите строго,просто нужен именно такая реализация чтоб я понимал что к чему)),а что касается использования объектов то это уже не интересно(просто создать и все)
https://bit.ly/2HQDKIc вот похожая тема,

Comment: Ну тут сильно зависит от того как вы будете эти объекты использовать. В самом простом случае, если N известно до компиляции, можно просто создать нужное количество экземпляров в статическом конструкторе и поместить, например, в массив, потом выдавать их через статический метод в зависимости от параметра. Если создание объектов накладное, если N известно только во время исполнения, то все немного усложнится

Comment: Предположем самый простой случай. <<создать нужное количество экземпляров в статическом конструкторе и поместить, например, в массив, потом выдавать их через статический метод в зависимости от параметра.>> тогда можно пожалуйста вышесказанное именно через код а не описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

public class A
{

    static int n = 8;

    static A[] mas=new A[n];

    public static A[] fff()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(mas[i]==null)
            {
                mas[i] = new A();
            }
        }
        return mas;
    }

    A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("constructor");
    }
}

public class M
{
    static void Main()
    {

        A[] ob = A.fff();

        Console.WriteLine("ob2");

        for (int i=0;i<ob.Length;i++)
        { 
        Console.WriteLine(ob[i].GetHashCode());
        }

        A[] ob2 = A.fff();

        Console.WriteLine("ob2");

        for (int i = 0; i < ob2.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ob2[i].GetHashCode());
        }

    }
}
```